# How to host an MS Teams app in a container with an nginx proxy pass

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, containers, microsoft-teams

I have to host my teams app under https://mysite/myapp

The host is ruled by nginx like that

```
location /myapp {
    proxy_pass http://ip:port;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
}
```

http://ip:port is the real host of the teams app inside a docker container.

This is the nginx config for the container

```
server {

  listen 80;
  
  location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

  location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }
}
```

this is the docker file (a part of it)

```
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=build /nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=build /build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

If I try http://ip:port/tab I see
[image]

If I try https://mysite/myapp/tab I can't see any message from the page and the browser seems to load the index.html page

Is there a way to make the react routing work with this settings?

Comment: just a note
the teams app was created following those steps
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/build-your-first-app/build-and-run

in development mode (localhost:3000/tab with ngrok) is working fine

Comment: You can try to host your solution over ngrok server and put the URL in tab. This will work for sure

Comment: Do you use only Tabs or also Bot and Message Extensions? Tabs don't need the Microsoft Azure Bot Framwork, so it is easier to debug / test locally